# Reading from Multiple long .txt files in Qt

Tags: qt, readfile, qfile

I am trying to read data from Multiple files in Qt. 
This how I am doing it:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

 QString path = "C:/MyDevelopment/readfiles";
 QDir dir(path);
 QStringList filters;
 filters << "*.txt";

 foreach ( QString fileName, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files) )
 {

     QFile readFile(fileName);
     if(!readFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
      {
        qDebug("Failed to read file.....");
        //return ;
      }
      QTextStream in(&fileName);
      while (!in.atEnd())
      {
          QString line = in.readLine();
           qDebug() << line;
      }

 }
```

it is always going in failed  to open. what i am doing wrong here?? 
in mentioned directory all files are .txt files.

Comment: Did you debug what part is not working? Do you receive correct list of names from dir.entryList() call?

Comment: Hi. Would you mind printing out readFile.errorString() to know about what open() complies ?

Comment: yes it returns me correct name of files in the directory. but not reading them.